# Excel Sum If Array in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm new to DAX and trying to port this use case.  I need to create an object in a new column that sums multiple conditions: (1) if the account number in the cell equals anything else in the column and (2) if the year in the cell equals any in the column and (3) if the period number is less than or equal to any in the column, then sum the balance. Basically period 0 is the opening balance and anything greater than 0 are the entries that have to debit or credit that balance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FjC9.png)

Comment: Do you need cumulative balance column as output?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the **Measure** code for the column **Cumulative balance**, you can try this below code-

```
cumulative_balance = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[Balance]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(
            your_table_name,
            your_table_name[GL Acct],
            your_table_name[Year]
        ),
        your_table_name[Period] <= MIN(your_table_name[Period])
    )
)
```

Output-

[image]

Comment: Will this work if my report contains multiple linked tables, where GL Acct is one table, and Period and Year are another?